# How to find shortest path between nodes on a directed graph in neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, shortest-path, directed-graph

Using graph algorithms extension and the inbuilt shortest-path search in neo4j does not look at the direction of the relationships as long as 2 nodes are connected. Is there a way to query the graph db to include the directionality of the relationships connecting nodes, or would you have to code dijikstra's from scratch without leveraging neo4j and its graph algorithm library capabilities?

I'm currently using a query structured in this fashion:

```
MATCH (start:Db_Nodes{uid:"xxx"}),(end:Db_Nodes{uid:"yyy"}) CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, "weight") YIELD nodeId, cost MATCH (node) WHERE id(node) = nodeId RETURN node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APOC procedure [apoc.algo.dijkstra](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#path-finding) should work for you.

For instance, if you want the shortest weighted path with only outgoing relationships from `start` to `end` (regardless of relationship type):

```
MATCH (start:Db_Nodes{uid:"xxx"}), (end:Db_Nodes{uid:"yyy"})
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, '>', 'weight') YIELD path, weight AS totalWeight
RETURN path, totalWeight;
```